# How do I convert a ContentValues object for use in an execSQL() call?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to be able to take a ContentValues object and use that in a sqlite statement.

```
ContentValues cv;
cv.put( "id", 1 );
cv.put( "name", "Bob" );
cv.put( "isCEO", true );
```

Normally, I would hardcode the request as such:

```
db.execSQL( "Insert or replace into Employee (id, name, isCEO) values (1, 'Bob', true)" );
```

What's the best way to convert cv into the string "(id, name, isCEO) values (1, 'Bob', true)"?  Also, is there a way to get back a success/fail status for the sqlite operation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'replace' method of SQLiteDatabase. e.g.

```
ContentValues cv;
cv.put( "id", 1 );
cv.put( "name", "Bob" );
cv.put( "isCEO", true );
db.replace(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
```

For this to work, the 'id' column has to be a PRIMARY key column in your table.

The response of the 'replace' method is a long value:

```
the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting ContentValues into strings, let the framework do it for you.

db.insertWitOnConflict("Employee", null, cv, CONFLICT_REPLACE);

See this for more detail:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, int)